# Paragraph indenting in an mdframed environment

Tags: environments, indentation, paragraphs, mdframed

I'm using the `mdframed` package and I've defined my own environment. But it seems that paragraph indentation doesn't work inside a `mdframed` environment.

I've used the `settings` option of `mdframed` to set parindent inside but it doesn't seem to work. However when I explicitly add `\setlength{\parindent}{\defparindent}`, which is a rather ugly solution, it indents the first line too a little bit. So either way this whole thing is not okay.

How can I tell my `singleframed` environment to set `\parindent` inside itself?

[image: mdframed parindent]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,%
innerleftmargin=\parindent,%
skipabove=0.6\baselineskip,%
skipbelow=0.6\baselineskip,%
innertopmargin=0.4\baselineskip,%
innerbottommargin=0.4\baselineskip]{mdframed}

\newlength{\defparindent}
\setlength{\defparindent}{\parindent}

% The singleframed environment
\newmdenv[linewidth=0.4pt,%
linecolor=black,%
backgroundcolor=white,%
settings={\setlength{\parindent}{\defparindent}}]{singleframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{singleframed}
qwerty

qwerty
\end{singleframed}

\begin{singleframed}
\setlength{\parindent}{\defparindent}
qwerty

qwerty
\end{singleframed}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't able to use the settings provided by `mdframed`. So I just defined a new enviroment. I think for changing it in `mdframed` you would need to patch package internals. Anyway this Solution has no problem with additional spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,%
innerleftmargin=\parindent,%
skipabove=0.6\baselineskip,%
skipbelow=0.6\baselineskip,%
innertopmargin=0.4\baselineskip,%
innerbottommargin=0.4\baselineskip]{mdframed}

\newlength{\defparindent}
\setlength{\defparindent}{\parindent}

% The singleframed environment
\newmdenv[linewidth=0.4pt,%
linecolor=black,%
backgroundcolor=white]{singleframed}

\newenvironment*{singleframedindent}{\begin{singleframed}\setlength{\parindent}{\defparindent}\ignorespaces}{\end{singleframed}}
\begin{document}



    \begin{singleframedindent}
    qwerty\\
    qwerty

    qwerty
    \end{singleframedindent}


\end{document}
```

Result is:
[image]

You wouldn't have any problem with the space in your example if you would do:

```
\begin{singleframed}
\setlength{\parindent}{\defparindent}%
qwerty

qwerty
\end{singleframed}
```

The new line after `setlength` is the cause for the additional space. By using the comment tag you don't have any problems.

Answer (score 6):

With the current version on [github](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed) (upload to CTAN today) you will get the following output of your example:
[image]

Comment: An official patch is of cause better than my solution ;) great delay between "bug report" and patch!

Comment: Now I'm in a bit of trouble which answer should I accept. @someonr's answer is great, but I think I'm going to use your new code, Marco. Any idea when is it going to make it in TeX Live?

Comment: @szantaii: Accept the answer of someonr. He found a quick solution.

Comment: I would accept Marco Daniel Solution. According to [here (meta.SX)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) you should "accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally."

Comment: @MarcoDaniel With `1.9b`, it does not work.