# how to indent the first line of an mdframed environment?

Tags: indentation, mdframed

i've been requested to indent the first paragraph in an environment defined with `mdframed`.

i've looked at the question [Paragraph indenting in an mdframed environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40553), and while it provides a workaround, there
really has to be a more subtle way of doing this.  (i can't find any indication in
the manual that this facility is provided; an option like `[indentfirst = true]` would
be really nice.)

here's the test file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% define (using mdframed) a highlighted block with a double line on the
% left along the (inside) edge of the text block.
%
\mdfdefinestyle{twolined}{%
   leftline=true,rightline=false,topline=false,bottomline=false,%
   outerlinewidth=.7pt,innerlinewidth=.7pt,middlelinewidth=2pt,%
   outerlinecolor=black,innerlinecolor=black,middlelinecolor=white,%
   innerleftmargin=6pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,%
   innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt,%
%   splittopskip=0pt,splitbottomskip=0pt.%
   skipabove=.5\baselineskip,skipbelow=.5\baselineskip
}
\newmdenv[%
   leftline=true,rightline=false,topline=false,bottomline=false,%
   outerlinewidth=.7pt,innerlinewidth=.7pt,middlelinewidth=2pt,%
   outerlinecolor=black,innerlinecolor=black,middlelinecolor=white,%
   innerleftmargin=6pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,%
   innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt,%
%   splittopskip=0pt,splitbottomskip=0pt.%
%   skipabove=.5\baselineskip,skipbelow=.5\baselineskip%
   skipabove=1\baselineskip,skipbelow=.5\baselineskip%
]{linedintro}

% patch the command on which linedintro is based, to try to restore the
% paragraph indentation on the first line.
%
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\mdf@lrbox
   {\parindent\z@}{\parindent\normalparindent\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Some unindented random text.

\begin{linedintro}
First paragraph within the lined environment.
Add some text to make it two lines long.

Second paragraph within the lined environment.  Make it two lines long.
\end{linedintro}

\noindent Some more unindented random text.
\end{document}
```

output:

[image: output of example code]

i've tried resetting other instances of `\parindent`, but to no effect.  (i may just
be looking in the wrong place, but it's not obvious what *is* the right place.)

if i rename the environment in the definition to `xlinedintro` and add a "derivative"
environment

```
\newenvironment{linedintro}{%
  \begin{xlinedintro}
  \parindent\normalparindent
  \hspace*{\normalparindent}\ignorespaces
 }{%
  \end{xlinedintro}%
}
```

this will force the indent on the first paragraph.  but the real situation is quite a
bit more complicated, and sometimes there is something else (a `marginnote`) that must
come between the beginning of the environment and the actual text, so it's necessary
to be careful with the input to avoid extra unwanted space.

*is* there a better place to apply a patch?  or some other way to accomplish the
indentation with more subtlety?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can offer a patch for `linedintro` that in turn patches `\mdf@lrbox` and `\mdf@trivlist` (locally) for adding the required indentations.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% define (using mdframed) a highlighted block with a double line on the
% left along the (inside) edge of the text block.
%
\mdfdefinestyle{twolined}{%
   leftline=true,rightline=false,topline=false,bottomline=false,%
   outerlinewidth=.7pt,innerlinewidth=.7pt,middlelinewidth=2pt,%
   outerlinecolor=black,innerlinecolor=black,middlelinecolor=white,%
   innerleftmargin=6pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,%
   innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt,%
%   splittopskip=0pt,splitbottomskip=0pt.%
   skipabove=.5\baselineskip,skipbelow=.5\baselineskip
}
\newmdenv[%
   leftline=true,rightline=false,topline=false,bottomline=false,%
   outerlinewidth=.7pt,innerlinewidth=.7pt,middlelinewidth=2pt,%
   outerlinecolor=black,innerlinecolor=black,middlelinecolor=white,%
   innerleftmargin=6pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,%
   innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt,%
%   splittopskip=0pt,splitbottomskip=0pt.%
%   skipabove=.5\baselineskip,skipbelow=.5\baselineskip%
   skipabove=1\baselineskip,skipbelow=.5\baselineskip%
]{linedintro}

% patch the command on which linedintro is based, to try to restore the
% paragraph indentation on the first line.
%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\indentforlinedintro}{%
  \patchcmd\mdf@lrbox{\parindent\z@}{\parindent\normalparindent\relax}{}{}%
  \patchcmd\mdf@trivlist{\itemindent\z@}{\itemindent\normalparindent}{}{}%
}
\patchcmd{\linedintro}{\begin}{\indentforlinedintro\begin}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

Some random text.
Some random text.
Some random text.
Some random text.
Some random text.
Some random text.
Some random text.
Some random text.

\begin{linedintro}
First paragraph within the lined environment.
Add some text to make it two lines long.

Second paragraph within the lined environment.  Make it two lines long.
\end{linedintro}

\noindent Some more unindented random text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

A key `indent=` might be very useful indeed.

Comment: beautiful!  i wouldn't have thought of patching the environment just defined; clearly i need more practice with patching.  thank you.  and i'll submit a request to the author of `mdframed` for an `indent` key.